# How to creat a question Class in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXJlR.png)

```dart
class Question { 
  String questionText; 
  bool questionAnswer; 

  Question(String q, bool a) { 
    questionText = q; 
    questionAnswer = a; 
  } 
}
```

What is the wrong here ?

Comment: What's wrong is that you are pasting an image, not text.  Please use text here.

Comment: class Question {

  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question(String q, bool a) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }

}

Comment: Non-nullable instance field 'questionAnswer' must be initialized.

Comment: Non-nullable instance field 'questionText' must be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question(this.questionText, this.questionAnswer);
}
```